# HTTP status code for a client request whose transactional record is deleted

Tags: java, rest, http

I have a distributed system which contains of 3rd party application that send request to a head end system via an adapter. when a request is sent to the head end the adapter creates a service request in the db and there is a duration within which a response is expected to arrive at the adapter from the head end else the service request will be timed out and deleted from the database. Now when the Service request is timed out the head end system hits the rest api in the adapter(POST) with a response(or request in REST terms) , what should the http code adapter should respond with - 200,404,410 or something else .

Answer (score 2):

Return 404 "Not Found" status code.

Check this https://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html for HTTP Status Codes reference.

The most important parts are:

> The server has not found anything matching the Request-URI. No
>   indication is given of whether the condition is temporary or
>   permanent. The 410 (Gone) status code SHOULD be used if the server
>   knows, through some internally configurable mechanism, that an old
>   resource is permanently unavailable and has no forwarding address.
>   This status code is commonly used when the server does not wish to
>   reveal exactly why the request has been refused, or when no other
>   response is applicable.